# I cant install sound for my PC. If I install win XP on virtual box, then how can I use Win xp sound driver

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I cant install sound for my PC on ubuntu 12.4. If I install win XP on virtual box, then how can I use Win xp sound driver not my ubuntu 12.4 who are not working, is it possible? Or maybe You can suggest any other operation system in wich I could use sound in virtual box even I dont have sound on MY ubuntu 12.4
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "cant install sound"? Are you talking about a sound card or a sound driver? Can you not hear any sound? Currently, this question is very vague and lacks important details.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual Box uses "virtual" hardware that communicates with your host operating (this case Ubuntu) system.  If Ubuntu doesn't see the hardware, Virtual Box can't communicate with the hardware.